# Hide Pipelines, Artifacts and Project Settings from Stakeholder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-boards

I am evaluating Azure Boards / Azure DevOps and I wish to restrict what a Stakeholder (in this case, a customer) can see and do.

I have managed to limit what a Stakeholder can do, but is it possible to completely hide the Pipelines, Artifacts and Project Settings panes from Stakeholder?

Se the image. I want to completely hide the panes marked in red.

[Image of panes to be hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4vnI.png)

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if we can show/hide the DevOps Services in top-level, based on a specific role. This is only available for the project level.

[image: Turning On Off Azure DevOps]

https://dailydotnettips.com/turning-azure-devops-service-on-or-off/

and these settings can only be controlled by the Project / Org administrator.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot get rid of the Pipelines from the view for the stakeholders. Yes, we can turn off the pipelines service from the project settings overview page, thus the pipelines node will disappear from the view. However **it's applied to entire project, that means all other users also cannot see the pipelines**.

As a workaround you can manage security for all pipelines and Artifacts for each project, just deny all of the related permissions for the stakeholder.

In addition, I found a related [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365834/better-permission-management-user-interface-identi.html), you can follow and vote this ticket to get the latest news.